# Is there a way to create a VM from a kernel and an initrd, using virt-manager?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, bootloader, kvm, initrd

Until now I used QEMU\KVM and was able to start a VM from a kernel image and an initrd file (skipping the bootloader). I want to start using virt-manager to manage my VMs, but it looks like there is no option to use this method anymore but only to create VMs from ISO images etc.

Is there anyway to make it work or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, but you have to trick it a little bit. Select 'Import', and give it any file as a disk image, just to get past the page. Click through to the end of the Wizard, select 'Customize before install'. Under the Boot page, you'll see an option to specify kernel + initrd. Remove the disk with the fake disk image